# crash in objc_object::release()

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I have a crash in my app, here is the call stack:

```
Crashed: com.apple.NSURLSession-work
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1829d17f4 objc_object::release() + 16
1  libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x18318ca5c _Block_release + 152
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x1830ecae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x1831297a8 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$armv81 + 416
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x183132acc _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 908
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x18312b074 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81 + 248
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x18312bad8 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 328
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x18312c47c _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$armv81 + 332
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x18313444c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$armv81 + 612
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18341fe70 _pthread_wqthread + 860
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18341fb08 start_wqthread + 4
```

I do not know how to replicate this crash, do you have any ideas what can cause such a crash?

Answer (score 8):

As a rule, crashes in release() are caused by releasing an invalid object.  This can be caused by a number of things:

- If your app is manually memory managed (non-ARC), this can by caused by over-releasing an object.
- If a non-zeroing weak reference to an object exists (often in some non-ARC class in the OS itself), this can be caused by that code releasing the reference after the object is destroyed (though this usually causes crashes in objc_msgSend).
- If you are manipulating a variable that retains an object, and try to change it in multiple threads simultaneously without that variable being marked as atomic, you can cause things like this to happen.

What's curious is that this involves a block, which should be retained by the queue while the block is running, so short of manual retain-release bugs, this should not be possible unless the object being released is something other than the block itself (or unless the last reference to that block is somehow being simultaneously released from multiple threads concurrently).

What that leaves is objects contained within your block:

- Are any of them double pointers, perhaps (e.g. NSError **inOutParam)?  You need to separately strongly retain those outside the block if you want to use them in a block.
- Are any of them weak?  If so, you need to make them strong inside the block before use (but I'd expect that to cause an objc_msgSend crash).
- Are you accessing any sort of shared resource (object, dictionary, array) from multiple threads?  If so, do you have appropriate synchronization (for a property, declared atomic; for a dictionary or array, with all accesses to that dictionary or array wrapped with @synchronized)?

Obviously, there's nowhere near enough information to say with certainty why you're experiencing this crash, but these are some of the things you should look for.  There are, no doubt, others that I'm not thinking of off the top of my head.

Hope that helps.